# Recursive button id in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I generate some buttons recursively, and that's how they are getting their id:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="<?php echo $speelgoedid?>" >TERUGBRENGEN</button>
```

I need to pass that id to a JQuery / AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-class").click(function(){
  var spid=$(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
                url:'insert.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    spid:spid
                },
               success:function(data){
                   $("#spid").focus();location.reload();

               }
            });
  });
});
```

The code of insert.php:

```
$speelgoedid=$_POST['spid'];
```

and using that to execute a query.

When I test the value of spid in insert.php, nothing is there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you `console.log`d `spid` in javascript? How about inspect dom and see if Id's are on buttons?

Comment: The button does not have `btn-class` class, so the click event does not fire up the code posted.

Comment: thanks, PeterKA This small detail escaped my attention !

Comment: "When I test in ..php" - you should test in javascript first, then the browser (network tab) *then* .php

Comment: @JamesBB so did that fix your problem?

Comment: Do all buttons have `id="<?php echo $speelgoedid?>"`? Because `id`s should be unique in a document

Comment: `$("#spid")` should instead be `$("#" + spid)` since you're looking to use the **value of** the variable `spid` and not the string `"spid"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PeterKA correctly pointd out, the buttons don't have the btn-class, but btn-primary.
Correcting this solved the problem.
Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you miss a semicolon at the end in the php code?

Like this:

```
id="<?php echo $speelgoedid;?>"
```